# R: sending email with sendmailR - "invalid host argument" error

Tags: r, email

I've downloaded the sendmailR package, but I'm having trouble sending an email. I've seen that there are several other posts on this, but I haven't been able to correct the problem.

My code looks as follows:

> smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name =
>   "xxx@gmail.com", 
>                 passwd = "yyy", ssl = TRUE)
>
> mailControl=list(smtpServer=smtp)
>
> sendmail(from = sender, to = receiver, subject = title, msg =
>   bodyWithAttachment, control = mailControl)

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'host' argument
```

I don't know if I'm using the correct port, or how to check (I've tried several that I've found online). Also, the host name is the one I found in a post about gmail accounts. Not sure if there is some way I can check if the security on my own computer is blocking it somehow?

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I have had no luck in sending from gmail's smtp server using sendmail.  I can't recall the problem, but I tried a number of solutions.

However, it is possible using the Postmarkapp API. It works using Hadley's postmarkapp.R (https://gist.github.com/hadley/5707759). You can sign up for a free API key at https://postmarkapp.com/.

A very helpful person in Sweden sent me this explanation months ago:
Steps needed, after signing up at postmarkapp.com and getting Hadley's script at https://gist.github.com/hadley/5707759

1. Copy your API key from postmarkapp.com (in Credentials tab under your server name)
   c80dc162-ad1c-44e8-b406-e9921fd8d2c3
2. In R, write: Sys.setenv(POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY= your-copied-api-key-here)
   Sys.setenv(POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY=  “c80dc162-ad1c-44e8-b406-e9921fd8d2c3”)  # with quotes
3. In the file from which you want to send the email, use the following code:

source('../postmarkapp.r')  #or the path to your postmarkapp.r wherever you store it

source("C:/Users/Rees/Documents/R/R Scripts/sendgmailwithpostmarkfromHadleygist.R")

mailtext <- "Good morning Rees, \nThis should be sending you emails from R in no time. \nBest regards, \nKristbjorn"

send_email(to = '...', from = '...', subject = '...', body = mailtext, attachments = 'path-to-file')  #or skip attachments

This should work. However, if the code fails in sourcing the postmarkapp, it is probaly due to dependent Libaries. The app depends on:
library(base64enc)
library(RJSONIO)
library(httr)
If any of these are not insatalled you need to do so. Note that httr is stored on github which needs to be installed using install_github from the devtools package: http://www.rstudio.com/projects/devtools/

One trick I use to send to multiple recipients, while spending only one credit at PostmarkApp, is to send the file to my own email address and have a rule in outlook forwarding the mail to multiple addresses. This should save you a few bucks as well, but of course it introduces a new point of potential failure in the chain wich has to be monitored.

I just got the solution to sending to multiple recipients. Found it on http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-build.html

1. You can pass multiple recipient addresses in the ‘To’ field and the optional ‘Cc’ and ‘Bcc’ fields. Separate multiple addresses with a comma. Note that Postmark has a limit of twenty recipients per message in total. You need to take care not to exceed that limit. Otherwise you will get an error.
   So, you were on the right track in trying sprintf. Maybe you have it already. I use:

to = c("addressone", "addresstwo") 
to = paste(to, collapse=', ')

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, sendmailR does not support SSL. Hence you are unable to send emails via smtp.gmail.com.

But you could try  the mailR package (https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR) that should work:

```
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "<html>The apache logo - <img src=\"http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif\"></html>",
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          attach.files = c("./download.log", "upload.log"),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
send.mail(from = "user@gmail.com",
          to = "user2@gmail.com",
          subject = "Hello",
          body = "Hello R",        
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "user@gmail.com", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),              
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
           smtp=list(host.name="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))
```

This did worked for me.