# Sending Email's From R

Tags: r, email

I am trying to send emails from R.

I tried to do this with two different libraries:

- mailR ([R: sending email with sendmailR - "invalid host argument" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527994/r-sending-email-with-sendmailr-invalid-host-argument-error))

This library seems to install, but not load:

```
 install.packages("mailR",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/mailR_0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 751677 bytes (734 KB)
downloaded 734 KB

package ‘mailR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEDCLcj\downloaded_packages

> library(mailR)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mailR’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘mailR’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

I wonder if this is because I am using an older version of R?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
```

- sendmailR

This library installs, but the email will not send:

```
Server<-list(smtpServer= "smtp.example.io")

from <- sprintf("<me123@hotmail.com>","The Sender") # the sender’s name is an optional value
to <- sprintf("<me123@hotmial.com>")
subject <- "Test email subject"
body <- "Test email body"

sendmail(from,to,subject,body,control=list(smtpServer= "smtp.example.io"))

Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  smtp.example.io:25 cannot be opened
```

I tried to look into the documentation for these libraries but I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: For the first error, make sure you have installed rJava correctly and restart R. (see https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/). For the second, "smtp.example.io" is not a real smtp server address. You need to change that to a server you actually have access to.

Answer (score 0):

`mailR` won't work because, as you stated, you are using an older version of R. You need to use atleast version `4.0.5`. You could also try find an older version of the library that supports R version `4.0.3`.

For `sendmailR`, the example server you are using doesn't actually exist. Try replace with a valid server and try again.